# Cannot read property 'push' of undefined in Ionic with MQTT in if statement only

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

First of all I am new to Ionic and MQTT. Would be great if someone help me with this issue. I am trying to push a page in ionic CLI PRO 4.3.1. When a message arrives (1) from MQTT topic, I am trying to open a new page. The navCtrl statement is only working outside of the if statement. **I am getting Cannot read property 'push' of undefined error.**

My code is below;

add-device.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, ModalController, NavParams, NavController, ViewController } from 'ionic-angular';
import {Paho} from 'ng2-mqtt/mqttws31';
import { SignupPage } from '../pages';


@IonicPage()

@Component({
  selector: 'page-add-device',
  templateUrl: 'add-device.html'
})


export class addDevicePage {

  hello: any;
  pushPage: any;
  params: Object;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, 
    public modalCtrl: ModalController, 
    private viewCtrl: ViewController,
    public navParams: NavParams) {}

deviceIDsend() {

console.log("MQQT");
var mqttHost = 'broker.mqttdashboard.com';
var port = 8000; // port for above

this.client = new Paho.MQTT.Client
(mqttHost, port,
  "web_" + parseInt(Math.random() * 100, 10));// set callback handlers
    console.log("connecting to "+ mqttHost +" "+ port);

this.client.onConnectionLost = this.onConnectionLost;
this.client.onMessageArrived = this.onMessageArrived;
 //this.client.subscribe = this.subscribe;
//var options = {
  //  useSSL: true,
    //userName: "username",
    //password: "password",
    //onSuccess:this.onConnect,
    //onFailure:this.doFail
 // }

  // connect the client
this.client.connect({onSuccess:this.onConnect.bind(this)});}
// called when the client connects
onConnect(client) {
console.log("onConnect");

this.client.subscribe("/j/" +this.device_id);
this.message = new Paho.MQTT.Message(this.device_id);
this.message.destinationName = "/j/" +this.device_id;// message.qos = qos;

console.log(this.device_id);
 this.client.send(this.message);}

onMessageArrived(message) {
  console.log("onMessageArrived:" + message.payloadString);

  if (message.payloadString == "1") {
             console.log('in');

    this.navCtrl.push('SignupPage');  
   }

   else{
        console.log('hello');
   }
}

onConnectionLost(responseObject) {
  if (responseObject.errorCode !== 0) {
    console.log("onConnectionLost:" + responseObject.errorMessage);
  }

}


}
```

add-device.html

```
<ion-header transparent>
  <ion-navbar transparent>
  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>
<ion-content class="background">
<ion-card>
  <form (submit)="deviceIDsend()">
  <ion-list>
        <h3 text-wrap style="padding-left: 8%">{{ 'j' | translate }}</h3>
        <p  text-wrap style="padding-left: 8%">{{ 'j' | translate }}</p>
      <div padding>
         <ion-item class="item3"> 
        <ion-label fixed>{{ 'NUMBER' | translate }}</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="email" type="text" name="deviceID" [(ngModel)]="device_id"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
</div>
    <div padding>
        <button class="LoginButton" ion-button block value="submit" 
        [navPush]="pushPage">{{ 'ADD' | translate }}</button>
      </div>
      </ion-list>
  </form>
</ion-card>

</ion-content>
```

add-device.module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { TranslateModule } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';

import { addDevicePage } from './add-device';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    addDevicePage,
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(addDevicePage),
    TranslateModule.forChild()
  ],
  exports: [
    addDevicePage
  ]
})
export class addDevicePageModule { }
```

Comment: show your whole component code, so we can figure out what's wrong with your `this.navCtrl` property

Comment: Do you have navCtrl passed in constructor?

Comment: Hello @Aragorn, I had included as public navCtrl: NavController. navCtrl is working outside of the if statement.

Comment: @ArtyomAmiryan I included whole component.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try the arrow function?
My only suspect is `this`, but I'm not 100% sure as OP says `this.navCtrl.push` works outside of the `if` block.

```
onMessageArrived = (message) => {
  console.log("onMessageArrived:" + message.payloadString);

  if (message.payloadString == "1") {
             console.log('in');

    this.navCtrl.push('SignupPage');  
   }

   else{
        console.log('hello');
   }
}
```